# gitlab changing project path

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-push

I forked some repository with only README.md/.gitignore files from specific gitlab repo on my profile, cloned it to remote repository on my desktop (`git remote add gitlab "clone_url"`, made some work&commits and pushed it on my fork `git push gitlab master`. Then I opened merge request to gitlab's master repository of that fork via gitlab UI.

Reviewer asked me to change chain directory. Lets say now I have something like:

`forked_repo/a/b/c/d/project` in merge request.

He want to have:

`forked_repo/x/project`

Thing is I don't want to change this chain directory on my desktop but want to push this project in such way like he want to have it.

What is suitable&clean why to achieve this?

Thanks for help.